# What would be the best approach to creating a function that does the summing of 3-day sales transactions and counting the 3-day sales transactions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
with open('POS.csv') as csvfile:
    my_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    fricnt = 0
    satcnt = 0
    suncnt = 0
    sun = 0
    door = 0
    hdr = []
    sales = 0
    frisales = 0
    satsales = 0
    sunsales = 0
    total = 0
    totcnt = 0
    for row in my_reader:
        if door == 0:
            hdr.append(row)
            door = 1
        elif row[21] == 'Friday':
            frisales = frisales + float(row[11])
            fricnt += 1
        elif row[21] == 'Saturday':
            satsales = satsales + float(row[11])
            satcnt += 1
        elif row[21] == 'Sunday':
            sunsales = sunsales + float(row[11])
            suncnt += 1
        total = frisales + satsales + sunsales
        totcnt = fricnt + satcnt + suncnt
print('3-day Total Sales:', total, '3-day Average Sale:', total/totcnt)
```

I am trying to create a function that does the summing of 3-day sales amount transactions and counting of 3-day sales transactions. I know this should be simple but I am new to programming and could use some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compute your totals until the whole file is finished.  And you can use a dictionary to track your sales by day.

```
with open('POS.csv') as csvfile:
    my_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    door = 0
    hdr = []
    sales = {
        'Friday': 0,
        'Saturday': 0,
        'Sunday': 0
    }
    counts = {
        'Friday': 0,
        'Saturday': 0,
        'Sunday': 0
    }
    for row in my_reader:
        if door == 0:
            hdr.append(row)
            door = 1
        elif row[21] in sales:
            sales[row[21]] += float(row[11])
            counts[row[21]] += 1
total = sales['Friday']+sales['Saturday']+sales['Sunday']
totcnt = counts['Friday']+counts['Saturday']+counts['Sunday']
print('3-day Total Sales:', total, '3-day Average Sale:', total/totcnt)
```

Although now that I'm thinking about it, if you don't need the day totals separately, there's no need to keep three separate subtotals.  Just pile them all into one variable.

Comment: hmm I'll try this out

Answer (score 0):

consider using [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library, which provides lots of data processing primitives:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table


rows = (
    Table.from_csv("POS.csv", header=False)
    .update(COLUMN_11=c.col("COLUMN_11").as_type(float))
    .filter(c.col("COLUMN_21").in_({"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}))
    .into_iter_rows(list)
)

# this is where code generation happens, store for further reuse if needed
converter = c.aggregate(
    {
        "total": c.ReduceFuncs.Sum(c.item(11)),
        "average": c.ReduceFuncs.Average(c.item(11)),
    }
).gen_converter()

converter(rows)
```

if day by day statistics is needed, you could omit filtering by days of week and process like this:

```py
converter = c.aggregate(
    {
        "day_to_sales": c.ReduceFuncs.DictSum(c.item(21), c.item(11)),
        "day_to_count": c.ReduceFuncs.DictCount(c.item(21), c.item(11)),
    }
).gen_converter()
```

Here `day_to_sales` would be a dict, where keys are days of week and values would be sums of sales.

**Also, since you are working with money, consider using `decimal.Decimal`**